# how to say the sentence "I am walking on the steps of bus"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

When I catch the bus , I say `I caught the bus (or) I got the bus`. But I need to say I am walking on the steps of bus.
how can I convert that into a sentence? I don't have a clear idea.

Comment: ascend the bus steps, descend the bus steps, leap up the bus steps, run up the bus steps..

Comment: You should put your mobile phone away while walking up the steps of a bus. :)

Comment: What exactly you want? Tell me in *hindi*.

Comment: @MaulikV `Men bus pe chad raha hu`.  I need this sentence in english.

Comment: *I'm getting on to the bus* = Ben's answer is **the** answer if I know Hindi! :)

Comment: Sidenote: "I got the bus" probably means you bought, brought, or reserved a bus. I think you're looking for "I got on the bus"

Answer (score 11):

In English, if you just want to say that you're in the act of catching the bus, you don't explicitly mention the steps. You just say:

> I'm getting on the bus.

The [present progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_continuous_(English)) tense indicates that the action is happening right now, as you are speaking.

**Get on** is a phrasal verb that means (among many other things) to enter a large vehicle such as a bus, a truck, a boat, a train, or an airplane, by whatever way of entering it is appropriate: climbing up steps, climbing down a ladder, jumping onto a platform, walking along a ramp, etc. [Here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-on) is a dictionary definition.

Comment: but he needs the sentence for walking on the steps of the bus.

Comment: @sharon I'm only guessing that this is Bhuvanesh's intended meaning. But Maulik V has confirmed it. "Getting on the bus" does strongly suggest that you are walking up the steps of the bus. In English, you wouldn't mention the steps.

Comment: Could add _stepping on/onto the bus_ or _stepped on/onto the bus_

Comment: I would use "I'm climbing on the bus"

Comment: @JacobKrall That would generally mean that you were, well, climbing *on* the bus. Like, pretending you were spiderman, and climbing around on the outside of the bus.

Comment: @neminem Indeed all of these can mean doing something outside the bus as well as boarding it: “getting on the bus” = climbing onto the top of the bus; “climbing on the bus” = playing Spiderman; “stepping on the bus” = crushing it like Godzilla. It’s a wonder that anything can be said clearly in English.

Comment: @BenKovitz While that is technically true given the right context, I would argue that "getting on the bus" colloquially and without other context means "boarding the bus the normal way", while "climbing on the bus" would mean "climbing around like the bus was your personal play structure". And yes, "stepping on the bus", as opposed to "stepping *onto* the bus", would most likely mean that you were a giant. "Stepping onto the bus" would be another good way of saying you were boarding. For that matter, "boarding the bus" is also good. ;)

Comment: @neminem But “boarding the bus” could mean nailing wooden boards over the windows! :) Seriously, I agree, of course. The fact that “getting on the bus” is so much more common and ordinary makes me hesitate to add any alternatives to this answer (though they might make good alternative answers).

Comment: @neminem “Stepping onto the bus” = Godzilla doing step aerobics with the bus. ;)

Comment: @JacobKrall I think "getting on" would be more common than "climbing on", but "climbing" does emphasize the stairs.

Comment: Maybe "mounting the bus?"  That couldn't be misunderstood, could it @BenKovitz

Comment: To briefly imply one or more steps, and an upward as well as inward motion, you could simply say "I'm stepping UP INTO the bus". The converse would be "I'm stepping DOWN OFF the bus."

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments--and for "mounting"! :) I just made some edits to clarify the idea that in English you normally abstract out the entryway. @Adam

Answer (score 4):

*I'm boarding the bus.*

*I'm stepping onto the bus.*

Those sound the most natural to my ears.

Comment: +1 Welcome to ELL! BTW - since there are English speakers from so many parts of the world, it is good practice to call out where your ears are from if there is any chance that you are using a regional expression.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind.  I'm a native U.S. English speaker and I've lived throughout the U.S.

Answer (score 2):

To say you are walking specifically on the steps to the bus (that is, the emphasis is just as much on the fact you are on the *steps* as that you are getting onto the bus in general), I would say, "I am climbing the steps onto the bus". It is wordy, but I would say it is the best way to include the use of the steps in the action.

Comment: I'd probably say 'stairs', rather than 'steps', but that's about as naturally as you're going to be able to express this unusual sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

> *"But I need to say I am walking on the steps of bus. how can I convert that into a sentence?"*

If you want to mean you are getting onto the bus you could say :

> I'm getting on the bus

or

> I'm ascending the bus-steps

or

> I'm running up the bus-steps

The above three variations are already pointed out by **CopperKettle** and **Ben Kovitz** by the way.

However, if you want to mean that you are getting off the bus you could say :

> I'm alighting the bus

or

> I'm getting off the bus

or

> I'm running down the bus-steps

or

> I'm stepping off the bus

Interestingly, one can also use ***debus*** to mean getting off a bus (getting off any motor vehicle for that matter). However a bit of Googling suggests that it's more apt in a military context.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The hyphen here is unnecessary and unnatural. "Bus steps" is better. But an English speaker (or at least an American) probably wouldn't mention the physical steps at all unless it was very specifically relevant.

Comment: I stand corrected about the hyphen.
As for the "steps" part, I doubt the OP's a native English speaker, much less an American. Also, he explicitly mentioned in his query for suggestions on how to better express the act of running up or down the steps of a bus. ("But I need to say I am walking on the steps of bus") Unnatural as it might be, that's what he wanted to know. It's the reason I started my answer quoting a part of the question.

In any case, I mentioned other ways to convey the same. I probably should've mentioned that those were better alternatives.